# how to check variable existence and compare with the string in busybox?

Tags: shell, busybox, test

I want to use something like that

```
if [[ ! -z "$ENV" && $ENV == 'production' ]]; then echo "production"; else echo "dev"; fi
```

but in BusyBox it does not work :(

```
sh: 1: [[: not found
```

It looks like any combination AND or OR does not work in IF statement into busybox

Comment: Are you sure you are in the BusyBox shell (aka `ash`)? it looks more like you are simply in a POSIX shell such as `dash` that doesn't support the `[[` extended test operator. FWIW, current versions of `ash` seem to support the `${parameter:-word}` expansion.

Comment: There is not much point testing ENV for not-zero and then == something, just use test (with `[]` not `[[]]`) for equal: `if [ 'production' = "$ENV" ]`

Comment: You shouldn't use the `ENV` variable for that. `ENV` is a special variable for `sh`!

Comment: @steeldriver you are right it's apparently `dash`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the older `[` syntax

```
if [ -n "$ENV" -a "$ENV" = 'production' ]
```

(note I used `-n` rather than `! -z` because it reads easier, but it's the same thing).

Or we can simplify to an even older syntax by forcing the string to have a value:

```
if [ "x$ENV" = 'xproduction' ]
```

Finally, the `-n` test may not really be needed and you can possibly just do

```
if [ "$ENV" = 'production' ]
```

Comment: `-a`/`-o` have been obsoleted by POSIX as they make for unreliable test expressions even with modern implementations of `[` (try with `ENV='='` for instance). Use `[ -n "$ENV" ] && [ "$ENV" = production ]` (functionaly equivalent to `[ "$ENV" = production ]` in any case)

Comment: Beside the `"x$VAR"` trick, you can also use `[ production = "$ENV" ]` or `case $ENV in production)` for compatibility with very old `[` implementations that may otherwise choke on some values of `$ENV`.

Comment: Finally, if the point was to test for an _unset_ variable to avoid the effect of `set -u`, you can use `[ production = "${ENV-unset}" ]`

Answer (score 14):

`[[...]]` is a Korn shell construct also supported by `bash` and `zsh` but otherwise not a standard `sh` one (and not supported by any other shell).

`busybox` `sh` is based on `ash` that implements a subset of the POSIX specification of `sh` (in the POSIX locale, it is compliant for the most part) with very few extensions, and in particular, not this one.

**2019 edit**. a limited subset of ksh's `[[...]]` is now also supported by busybox ash when built with `ASH_TEST` and `ASH_BASH_COMPAT` and a much larger subset in `yash`.

In any case, when writing a `sh` script, you should stick to the POSIX `sh` specification. Scripts that use `[[...]]` should invoke `ksh`, `bash` or `zsh` explicitly. `bash` is also a mostly POSIX sh compatible shell, but with a lot more extensions (including this one).

Testing for *x* being non-empty, and then being equal to `production` makes little sense. If *x* == `production`, then obviously it's not empty.

Do do string comparisons with the POSIX shell and utilities, you have a few options, the most obvious ones in this case are:

- the `[` utility aka `test`, generally built in the shell:

  ```
    if [ "$var" = production ]; then
      echo PROD
    fi
  ```
- the `case` construct:

  ```
    case $var in
      production) echo PROD;;
      "") echo EMPTY;;
      *) echo non-PROD;;
    esac
  ```

Now, you may want to check that the variable is *set* (as opposed to non-empty), prior to dereferencing it, in the case where the `nounset` option has been enabled (with `set -u` or `set -o nounset` or with `#! /bin/sh -u` as the she-bang line), as otherwise a `[ "$ENV" = production ]` would cause the shell to exit if `$ENV` was not set. To do that, you'd do:

```
if [ "${var+set}" = set ] && [ "$var" = production ]; then
  echo PROD
fi
```

(you should avoid the `-a` `[` AND operator as it's deprecated and unreliable).

Though a better and more canonical way to  do it would be:

```
if [ "${var-}" = production ]; then
  echo PROD
fi
```

`nounset` does not trigger on `${var+string}` or `${var-string}` expansions. `${var-}` expands to the content of `$var` if the variable is set or the empty string otherwise.

A few other notes:

`$ENV` is a special variable for `sh`. When started interactively, it's taken as the path to a file to read initialisations from (the equivalent of `~/.bashrc` for `bash`). You should not use it for other purposes.

You'll find that some old Unix shell scripting literature recommend to use `[ "x$var" = xproduction ]` or `[ production = "$var" ]` to do string comparison. That was to overcome bugs in some old versions of the `[` aka `test` utility that were confused by some values of `$var` like `!`, `(` or `-n`. It should not be needed on modern systems, but something to bear in mind for very old systems. In any case, the `case` construct doesn't have this kind of problem.

Other POSIX utilities that can do string comparison include `expr` and `awk`.

```
 awk_equal() { awk 'BEGIN{exit(!(""ARGV[1] == ""ARGV[2]))}' "$1" "$2"; }
 expr_equal() { expr "x $1" = "x $2" > /dev/null; }

 if awk_equal "$var" production; then
   echo PROD
 fi
 if expr_equal "$var" production; then
   echo PROD
 fi
```

Note the need to prepend `""` to the values with `awk` to make sure we get a string comparison (otherwise `1` would be considered equal to `01` or `1e0`), and `x`  in `expr` for the same reason but also to avoid problems with values being `expr` operators.

With both `awk` and `expr` (at least POSIXly), they are not really *equality* operators but a test for whether the two operands have equal sorting order, which may not necessarily be the same thing. For instance, on my system, `expr_equal ② ③` returns true, because neither ② nor ③ have a defined sorting order. Some `awk` implementations like `gawk`, `mawk` and busybox `awk` ignore that POSIX requirement and do a simple byte-to-byte comparison instead.

In any case, I can't think of any good reason why you'd prefer those over `[` or `case` here.